# How to create trigger with multiple substitutions variable in Google Cloud build with Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-build

I am working on Python code to create Google Cloud trigger, I am not able to add substitutions variable.

Currently I have below code

```
from google.cloud.devtools import cloudbuild_v1

client = cloudbuild_v1.CloudBuildClient()

build_trigger_template = cloudbuild_v1.types.BuildTrigger()

build_trigger_template.description = 'test to create trigger'
build_trigger_template.name = 'github-cloudbuild-trigger1'
build_trigger_template.github.name = 'github-cloudbuild'
build_trigger_template.github.pull_request.branch = 'master'
build_trigger_template.filename = 'cloudbuild.yaml'

response = client.create_build_trigger('dev',
                                       build_trigger_template)
```

I want to add two substitutions variables _ENV and _PROJECT, I tried below mentioned way but not working.

```
build_trigger_template.substitutions = {'_ENV': 'test',
                                        '_PROJECT': 'pro-test'}
```

**Error: AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to repeated field "substitutions" in protocol message object.**

Thanks,

Raghunath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with assigning protobuf object.

If you look on the object using `dir(build_trigger_template.substitutions)`

you'll find an `.update` method that will accept a dictionary.

so try the below, it should return `None` but your structure will be updated.

`build_trigger_template.substitutions.update({'_ENV': 'test',
                                        '_PROJECT': 'pro-test'})`